# Why Are So Many Actors from "Rome" in John Carter?

Tags: casting, john-carter, rome

I just saw the movie "[John Carter](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0401729/)" (and loved it). But I noticed that four actors in the movie who were also in the HBO miniseries "Rome". Does anyone know why? For instance, was there staff of "John Carter" who also worked on "Rome"?

Comment: I googled this while watching lol. I saw caesar and mark anthony, who else did you see?

Comment: I wish I'd written them down when I counted four. The only other Rome actor I see now is [Polly Walker](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0908116/).

Comment: there were more than 3 of rome actors johns lawyer was Poska of rome also the woman who changed into to time and space traveling guy was Pompei's wife in rome Iam pretty sure.

Comment: James Purefoy, Ciarán Hinds, Nicholas Woodeson, Polly Walker, is who I've seen so far.. yah wow..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [quick search](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt0384766,tt0401729) doesn't show any obvious behind-the-camera shared staff between the two.  *John Carter*'s Director and writers all came from Pixar.  *Rome*'s creators, who wrote almost all of the episodes of the show are mostly still working on TV shows.  One of them does some work writing TV shows and movies.  Expanding the search to directors of multiple episodes of *Rome*, I just see a mix of people working on other HBO shows since, and people who've moved on to TV shows on other networks, with the occasional movie writer.

But, none of that really proves the lack of a connection, just that one isn't easily found by searching resumes.

Answer (score 3):

The only connection I can find is that both [Marcia Ross](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0743638/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr9) (Casting Director, *John Carter*) and [Nina Gold](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0002274/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr43) (Casting Director, *Rome*) have used the services of the "[Cast It](https://www.castittalent.com/directorList.aspx)" audition company.

Comment: Good catch. Still, would a company like cast it be involved in choosing talent or even bringing talent to the attention of the casting directors?

Comment: @JohnSaunders it's speculation but it might just be that actors in HBO dramas have an "up and coming" screen appeal for casting agents. It had been awhile since *Rome* when *John Carter* came out but the four actors were certainly still on the map... Disney pictures was likely looking for the most recognizable talent to fill out the cast as they were taking something of a gamble with their movie lead (most notable at the time for his work on TV with Friday Night Lights - recognizable to the films demographic, but not a proven money maker as a movie lead).

Comment: @JohnSaunders Also, yes, I would imagine that Cast It would rank talent according to "who's hot" http://www.nytimes.com/2009/06/28/business/media/28steal.html